PIC16F1618 returning ADC values exceeding 10bits
I'm writing my first PIC16F1618 project.
I got stucked in a pretty strange error/behaviour.
This's the repository of the project:
Github repo
The problem is the value resulting from the ADC sampling:
    adc_result_t getADCValue(adc_channel_t channel) {
        adc_result_t sum = 0;
        adc_result_t sample;
        
        for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 32; i++ )
        {
            sample = ADC_GetConversion(channel); 
            sum += sample;
        }
        
        return sum >> 5; // Divide per 32 tramite shift
    }

The MCC generated function ADC_GetConversion() should start, wait for ADC input being stable, wait for the conversion to be completed and return the 10bit value conversion from ADC.
The result is packed in a adc_result_t value right aligned.
I'm feeding the input with 1.5V ... I'm expecting a value around 0x133 but instead I got values about 0x4d00 that's well over 10bits.
NB I'm using MCC generated code where possibile.

---- UPDATE ----
This's the screenshot of the ADC configuration:

But this's the code ADC_Initialize() generated code:
void ADC_Initialize(void)
{
    //ADPREF VDD; ADCS FOSC/64; ADFM left; 
    ADCON1 = 0x60;
...

left???? I'm a little bit disappointed... right align should mean 7th bit high... then +0x80?

It looks like the value is left-aligned rather than right-aligned. 0x133 << (16-10) =0x4cc0  is almost equal to 0x4d00

I had the same suspect but I checked it more than once and is set to be right aligned... :-(

You appear to have configured the ADC to produce left-justified results.

File mcc_generated_files/adc/src /adc.c line 58:  ADCON1 = 0x60;    According to PIC16(L)F1614/8 datasheet (page 196) the bit 7 of register ADCON1 (ADFM) is 1 for right-justified and 0 for left-justified. So actually ADCON1[7] = 0 (left). You should fix it manually in the file.

IMHO The software bugs in uC configurators aren't so rare.

I'm too unexperienced to testify about it but it sounds like a bug to me too...

Did you forget to press the Generate button after you've changed the configuration. Otherwise it seems a bug and you should report it.

I'm pretty sure I have generated the source code only with the right alignment set... and I'm also pretty sure that for several debug runs the data were right aligned.. then for some reason the configuration changed but I never pressed Generate button ... it's difficult to file a report without a precise event that triggered the bug but I will report if it happens again
